# How to mark points by whether or not they are within a polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have the longitude and latitude of bird observations across New Zealand, stored in `Count.df`, under the variables `count`, `longitude`, and `latitude`. However some of these are appearing offshore/in the ocean (it's a Citizen Science data set).

I would like to subset these points based off whether they fall outside of the information given in `maps::map("nz")`, for two reasons:

1. I would like to plot these offshore points on a map, perhaps using a different colour
2. For further analysis I will probably remove them from the data set.

How can I create a new variable in `Count.df` based on whether they fall inside/outside of the groups (1:3) delineated by `map("nz")`, which is saved as "nzmap.dat"?

Thanks, and please try to keep the coding lingo simple.

Subset of `Count.df`, I have over 17000 observations, here are 10. Please note that the value of "count" is of no interest for this question.

```
df <- readr::read_table2(
  "count longitude latitude
3 174.7889 -41.24632
1 174.7764 -41.25923
4 176.8865 -39.67894
1 174.7656 -36.38182
2 175.5458 -37.13479
2 175.5458 -37.13479
1 176.8862 -39.67853
1 170.6101 -45.84626
5 174.9162 -41.25709
2 176.8506 -39.51831"
)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include at least a sample of `Count.df` as plain text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately it's rather difficult to use `maps` data to spatially filter points, because the data is really for plotting and not so much for doing spatial operations with. Luckily, it's fairly easy to use the `sf` package to do this kind of spatial work.

1. First I get a New Zealand boundary from the `rnaturalearth` package, which is a convenient source of country borders. I do a few transformations to keep only the largest three polygons in the shapefile, since otherwise we'd plot a lot of far flung islands that likely aren't relevant to this map.
2. Then I generate some random points around New Zealand. You can see that the `tibble` is just a column of longitudes and a column of latitudes. We turn this into point geometries with `st_as_sf` and plot it, to show what it looks like.
3. Last, we can use `st_within` to check for each point whether or not it is inside the `nz` boundary. `st_within` returns a list of indices of polygons that the point is within for each point, so we can use `lengths` to get the result we want. Here anything that is `0` is not within the boundary and anything that is `1` is within the boundary. Plotting with this new `on_land` attribute shows that offshore points are appropriately coloured.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
library(rnaturalearth)

nz <- ne_countries(country = "New Zealand", returnclass = "sf", scale = "large") %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  mutate(area = st_area(geometry)) %>%
  top_n(3, area)
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(., "POLYGON"): repeating attributes for all sub-
#> geometries for which they may not be constant

points <- tibble(
  x = runif(1000, st_bbox(nz)[1], st_bbox(nz)[3]),
  y = runif(1000, st_bbox(nz)[2], st_bbox(nz)[4])
)
points
#> # A tibble: 1,000 x 2
#>        x     y
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  167. -44.5
#>  2  175. -40.9
#>  3  177. -43.8
#>  4  167. -44.8
#>  5  173. -39.3
#>  6  173. -42.1
#>  7  176. -41.9
#>  8  171. -44.9
#>  9  173. -41.2
#> 10  174. -39.5
#> # ... with 990 more rows
points <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
plot(nz$geometry, col = "red")
plot(points, pch = 19, cex = 1, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
points <- points %>% mutate(on_land = lengths(st_within(points, nz)))
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_within assumes that they are planar
plot(nz$geometry, col = "red")
plot(points, pch = 19, cex = 1, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I had some trouble getting your code to run because some additional packages were required "rnaturalearthhires" and "lwgeom", but after this everything worked fine. I applied your method to my own data without any issues and now that I have the on_land variable I should be able to visualise what I wanted using ggplot2 and maps .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `maps::map.where` and (if you want) a custom map containing only the 3 main islands:

```
nz3 = map("nz",c("North","South","Stewart"), fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
points$onland = is.na(map.where(nz3, points$x, points$y))
plot(points, col = ifelse(points$onland, 1, 2), pch=19)
```